# Not Able to Receive Email with Sendgrid

Tags: ruby, email, authentication, sendgrid

I am new to learning Ruby and am currently taking a class where we build our first app. I am trying to set up a user account where users receive a confirmation email when they sign up for an account, but no emails are being sent. I set up SendGrid and set up the following in config/environments/development.rb:

`config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`

Then I checked my console to see how the emails were being delivered. This is the output that I received:

```
Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 6.6ms

Sent mail to [xxxxxxx@xxx.com] (2373.5ms)
Date: Tue, 09 Dec 2014 12:15:30 -0500
From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
To: [xxxxxxx@xxx.com]
Message-ID: <54872e323970f_5ce3fd7e895315c203e2@Users-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome [xxxxxxx@xxx.com]!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=-Gi_zVPoo3yMVnbsuTq3">Confirm my account</a></p>

   (2.5ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 2457ms (ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 76ms (Views: 75.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/posts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/welcome.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500


Started GET "/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (22.6ms)


Started GET "/apple-touch-icon.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 12:15:32 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/apple-touch-icon.png"):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (22.6ms)
```

Comment: Awesome to hear you're learning rails :). Could you please update your question to include your config/environments/development.rb file? Please make sure to remove your username and password.

Comment: From the logs it appears that the mail was sent - did you check whether the request reached send-grid? Perhaps it was received in your spam folder?

Comment: Can you comment on what was the actual problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic documentation to implement this [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html). The email seems to be sent, so I can recommend checking two things:

- log in into sendgrid with your user/password and check that the email was sent, etc. If the email was sent, then the problem is in the receiver (spam, etc)
- review your configuration (ie. `config/environment.rb`), as you need to have something similar to the config below.

The config:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'your_sendgrid_username',
  :password => 'your_sendgrid_password',
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Hi! I have what looks like what you described above in initializers/setup_mail.rb:```if Rails.env.development? ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = { address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net', port: '587', authentication: :plain, user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'], password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'], domain: 'heroku.com', enable_starttls_auto: true } end```

Comment: ok, seems correct. Do you have the ENV variables set up in your environment? That is, if you put in the console `env | grep SENDGRID`, can you see your data there or is it initialized in your rails app?

Comment: Hey! So I tried `env | grep SENDGRID` but it didn't bring up anything. Yet `heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME
heroku config:get SENDGRID_PASSWORD` and `heroku addons` show that it's installed.